# Why do methods of classes that inherit from numpy arrays return different things?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's look at some very simple behaviour of numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
max_value = arr.max() # returns 5
```

Now I create a class which inherits from `np.ndarray`:

```
class CustomArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = np.array(*args, **kwargs).view(cls)
        return obj
new_arr = CustomArray([1,2,3,4,5])
```

I haven't actually changed any behaviour - I just made a nominal change in what class the object is.

And yet:

```
new_max_value = new_arr.max() # returns CustomArray(5)
```

The return value is an `CustomArray` instance? Why? `arr.max()` didn't return a `np.ndarray` instance, just a plain numpy integer.

Similarly, why do both `arr == new_arr` and `new_arr == arr` return `CustomArray` instances? Shouldn't the former call `arr.__eq__(new_arr)`, which should return a `np.ndarray` instance?

EDIT:

Note that I override the `__new__` method for the sake of easy constructors. E.g. the equivalent of `np.array([1,2,3,4,5])` can just be `CustomArray([1,2,3,4,5])`, whereas if I plainly inherit from `np.ndarray` I'd have to do something like `new_arr = CustomArray((5,))`; `new_arr[:] = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`.

Comment: Check how subclasses like `matrix` and `masked array` handle this issue.  Many methods/functions make sure the return value has the same subclass as the inputs.  Note the `max(axis=...)` should be some sort of array.  It's the scalar case the requires special handling.

Comment: I get that the scalar case is the special case, but that still leaves open the question of how my custom class, which doesn't seem to change any behaviour, still has different behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the numpy docs: **array_wrap** gets called at the end of numpy ufuncs and other numpy functions, to allow a subclass to set the type of the return value and update attributes and metadata.

```
class CustomArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, a, dtype=None, order=None):
        obj = np.asarray(a, dtype, order).view(cls)
        return obj

    def __array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context=None):
        return np.ndarray.__array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context)

c = CustomArray([1,2,3,4])
c.max() # returns 4
```