# Magic method __repr__ leads to AttributeError with __new__ method

Tags: python-2.7, class, methods, superclass

My goal is to give numpy.ndarray a different representation, since I want to represent some arrays with units. Thus, I programmed a class that inherits its attributes/ methods from numpy.ndarray. For the another representation I wanted to use the `__repr__` magic method like:

```
class Quantitiy(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, value, unit=None, dtype=None, copy=True, order=None, subok=False, ndmin=0):

        value = np.asarray(value)

        obj = np.array(value, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, order=order, 
                       subok=True, ndmin=ndmin).view(cls)

        obj.__unit = util.def_unit(unit)
        obj.__value = value

        return obj

    def __repr__(self):
        prefix = '<{0} '.format(self.__class__.__name__)
        sep = ','
        arrstr = np.array2string(self.view(np.ndarray), 
                                 separator=sep,
                                 prefix=prefix)

        return '{0}{1} {2}>'.format(prefix, arrstr, self.__unit)
```

So far this works fine. However, if I want to access the inherited methods from numpy.ndarray I get a `AttributeError` because `__repr__` cant resolve `self.__unit`.

I tried to solve this problem with a private method that defines the variable `self.__unit` and called it within the `__new__` method but without success:

```
class Quantitiy(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, value, unit=None, dtype=None, copy=True, order=None, subok=False, ndmin=0):

        value = np.asarray(value)

        obj = np.array(value, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, order=order, subok=True, ndmin=ndmin).view(cls)

        # Here I call the private method to initialize self.__unit.
        obj.__set_unit()
        obj.__value = value

        return obj

    def __repr__(self):
        prefix = '<{0} '.format(self.__class__.__name__)
        sep = ','
        arrstr = np.array2string(self.view(np.ndarray), separator=sep, prefix=prefix)

        return '{0}{1} {2}>'.format(prefix, arrstr, self.__unit)

    # New defined private class.
    def __set_unit(self, unit):
        self.__unit = util.def_unit(unit)
```

I can not solve this with something like `cls.__unit = util.def_unit(unit)` in the `__new__` method. I already tried to define a `__init__` method after `__new__`. Moreover, I tried to interchange the private methods with public methods.

What I expect:

```
>>> array = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
>>> q = Quantity(value, unit="meter / second")
>>> q
    <Quantitiy [[1,2,3,4],
                [5,6,7,8]] meter/second>
>>> q * q
>>> <Quantitiy [[ 1, 4, 9,16],
                [25,36,49,64]] meter**2/second**2>

>>> q.min()
>>> <Quantitiy 1 meter/second>
```

The actual result is:

```
>>> array = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
>>> q = Quantity(value, unit="meter / second")
>>> q
    <Quantitiy [[1,2,3,4],
                [5,6,7,8]] meter/second>
>>> q * q
>>> <Quantitiy [[ 1, 4, 9,16],
                [25,36,49,64]] meter**2/second**2>

# Up to here everything works fine.

>>> q.min()
>>> AttributeError: 'Quantitiy' object has no attribute 
    '_Quantitiy__unit'
```

Does anyone see the mistake and can help me?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private

Comment: Thank you @brunodesthuilliers. Sorry, I forget to mention that I already tried to change the private methods in public methods with no success.

Comment: Looks like I didn't read your code properly the first time.

Comment: Ok, I suspect something weird happening with numpy AND your rather baroque (and that's an understatement) implementation of  `Quantitiy.__new__`.  FWIW, you get the very same problem using "protected" (one single leading underscore) or even public names instead.   May I ask where you got the idea to implement `__new__` that way actually ? (I mean: is this a documented receipe with numpy or what ?)

Comment: I got it from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851182/why-do-methods-of-classes-that-inherit-from-numpy-arrays-return-different-things). Do you have a better idea how I could implement it? I'd be very grateful.  Yes, I get the same error with privat, protected and public names. But the error appears only if I try to access to numpy array methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer is - as usual - [in the FineManual](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.subclassing.html#slightly-more-realistic-example-attribute-added-to-existing-array) (and could be found searching for "subclassing numpy ndarray" - which is how I found it actually), and requires implementing `__array_finalize__(self, obj)` :

```
import numpy as np

class Quantitiy(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, value, unit=None, dtype=None, copy=True, order=None, subok=False, ndmin=0):

        value = np.asarray(value)
        x = np.array(value, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, order=order, subok=True, ndmin=ndmin)
        obj = x.view(type=cls)
        obj._unit = unit
        obj._value = value
        return obj

    def __repr__(self):
        print("repr %s" % type(self))
        prefix = '<{0} '.format(self.__class__.__name__)
        sep = ','
        arrstr = np.array2string(self.view(np.ndarray), 
                                 separator=sep,
                                 prefix=prefix)

        return '{0}{1} {2}>'.format(prefix, arrstr, self._unit)


    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        # see InfoArray.__array_finalize__ for comments
        if obj is None:
            return
        self._unit = getattr(obj, '_unit', None)
        self._value = getattr(obj, '_value', None)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been experimenting with `__array_finalize__` for a while, as I have also seen the manuals. I just didn't quite understand how to do it.  Thank you very much for your efforts and your time.